# How to highlight a word in shinydashboard in R?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I've found some suggestions of how to highlight a word in other contexts but these didn't work for my problem. Here's my code:

```
data<-data.frame(X=c("This is an example", "This is not"))
wordlist<-c("This","example","not")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(selectInput("stemmedw", label="Find A Word : ",wordlist))
  ),
  dashboardBody("Title", tabPanel("News",uiOutput("news"))) 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$news <- renderUI({
    pos<-unlist(gregexpr(input$stemmedw,data$X,fixed=TRUE))!=-1
    base<-data.frame(X=data[pos,], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    m2 <- data.frame(X=data[pos,], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    n<-dim(m2)[1]

    a2 <- list()
    for(i in seq_len(n)) {
      a2[[i]] <- valueBox(i,lapply(m2, "[[", i),  width = 100,color="blue")
    }
    tagList(a2)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like to highlight only the selected word in the text in valueBox. Maybe a different background color, bold style and/or a underline.
Ths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of using bold with `HTML`, just complete with the htmls tags you want:

```
data<-data.frame(X=c("This is an example", "This is not"))
wordlist<-c("This","example","not")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(selectInput("stemmedw", label="Find A Word : ",wordlist))
  ),
  dashboardBody("Title", tabPanel("News",uiOutput("news"))) 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$news <- renderUI({
    pos<-unlist(gregexpr(input$stemmedw,data$X,fixed=TRUE))!=-1
    base<-data.frame(X=data[pos,], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    m2 <- data.frame(X=data[pos,], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    n<-dim(m2)[1]

    a2 <- list()

    for(i in seq_len(n)) {
      a2[[i]] <- valueBox(i, HTML(gsub(input$stemmedw, paste0("<b>", input$stemmedw, "</b>"), m2$X[[i]], fixed = TRUE)), width = 100, color = "blue")
    }
    tagList(a2)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked! But I'm still looking for a different color in the background since the real thing that I want to do is in a very long text, so the bold style it's not so easy to find.

Comment: Quick answer : `paste0("<p style='background-color:red'>", input$stemmedw, "</p>")`. Just play with html

Comment: @RodrigoMiyamoto To add any CSS property you can use `span` and the `style` attribute. For example, for the background color you can do: `paste0("<span style='background-color: yellow;'>", input$stemmedw, "</span>")`.